# Django calling another model's upload_to inside a model

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have two models, **A** and **B**. Model **A** has an `upload_to` path and inside it, I also want to save a field from model **B** on the same path. Here's what I want to do:

```
def random_path(instance, filename):
    #creating random path each time it's called

class A(models.Model):
    imageA = models.ImageField(upload_to=random_path) # Randomly generated path
    def create_documentfiles(self):
        imageB = # Image 
        saveImageB = DocumentImage(imagefile=imageB)
        saveImageB.imagefile.upload_to = # Should be same path as imageA
        saveImageB.save()

class B(models.Model):
    imagefile = models.ImageField()
```

I could define `upload_to=random_path` in **B** model, but it would give me a different path. So, I want the `upload_to` for model **B** be defined in model **A**. Not sure if it is even possible. Django docs don't mention anything similar to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just very simple. Use `_meta` for this purpose. You can use get_field method to get the fields of the model like `imageA` in your case. Then access any attribute of that field using object notations.

```
upload_to_attr = ModelName._meta.get_field('foo').upload_to
```

more generic:

```
attr_value = ModelName._meta.get_field('foo').attr_name
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but `getupload = A._meta.get_field(imageA).upload_to` inside the **B** model gives me an "'A' has no '_meta' member" error. Is there any extra step to make it work?

Comment: Which version of django are you using? Param imageA will be in quotes. Followed from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/

Comment: I'm using the latest version. imageA was in quotes in my code, I forgot to include them. Should I be importing **A** if it is in `model.py`?

Comment: OK, it was a linting error in my VS Code. It functions properly.